# How to have an automatic scrollview

Tags: scrollview

Hi guys I badly need your help. I am making an automatic scrollview with timer but I got an error. Please help me out. Here is my code:

public void scrollRight(final ScrollView h){

```
        new CountDownTimer(10000, 25) { 
             public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) { 
                 h.scrollTo((int) (2000 - millisUntilFinished), 0); 
        }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
             }.start();}
```

**Error: The method scrollTo is undefined for the type scrollview android**

Answer (score 0):

Your exact code does not give me any problems. Perhaps you're importing a different ScrollView?